# On same row: last purchase quantity + date, and total quantity in stock (several stock places) - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the following result in SQL server:

From the purchase order rows, last purchase quantity + date from all item codes in the order rows table and from the warehouse table amount in stock for the item codes I get from the rows table.

Order rows:

```
ORDER_DATE  ITEM_CODE  QTY
2019-03-01    A         5 
2019-03-02    A         3 
2019-03-05    A         4 
2019-03-03    B         3 
2019-03-04    B         10
```

Warehouse:

```
ITEM_CODE  INSTOCK STOCKPLACE
A           10      VV 
A           3       LP 
A           8       XV 
B           5       VV
B           15      LP
```

Wanted result (Latest order date, latest order qty and total in stock):

```
ORDER_DATE ITEM_CODE   QTY  INSTOCK
2019-03-05    A         4   21
2019-03-04    B         10  20
```

I have tried some queries but only failed. I have a steep learning curve ahead of me :) Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select o.*, wh.*
from (select wh.item_code, sum(wh.instock) as instock
      from warehouse wh
      group by wh.item_code
     ) wh outer apply
     (select top (1) o.*
      from orders o
      where o.item_code = wh.item_code
      order by o.order_date desc
     ) o;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` with apply :

```
select t.*, wh.instock
from (select o.*, row_number () over (partition by item_code order by o.order_date desc) as seq
      from Order o
     ) t cross apply
     ( select sum(wh.instock) as instock
       from warehouse wh
       where wh.item_code = t.item_code 
     ) wh
where t.seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Orders aren't identified with a unique ID, and therefore if multiple Orders were to coincide on the same date, you have no way of telling which is the most recent order on that day.

Anyway, assuming that the database you posted is correct and an Order date + Item Code combines to form a unique key, you could use grouping and some CTE to get the desired output as follows.

```
;WITH MostRecentOrders (ITEM_CODE, ORDER_DATE)
AS (
    SELECT
        O.ITEM_CODE
        , MAX(O.ORDER_DATE) AS ORDER_DATE
    FROM
        #Order O
    GROUP BY ITEM_CODE
)
SELECT 
    O.ORDER_DATE
    , O.ITEM_CODE
    , O.QTY
    , SUM(WH.INSTOCK) AS INSTOCK
FROM
    #Warehouse WH
    INNER JOIN #Order O ON O.ITEM_CODE = WH.ITEM_CODE
    INNER JOIN MostRecentOrders MRO ON MRO.ITEM_CODE = O.ITEM_CODE 
        AND MRO.ORDER_DATE = O.ORDER_DATE
GROUP BY 
    O.ORDER_DATE
    , O.ITEM_CODE
    , O.QTY
ORDER BY O.ITEM_CODE
```

Comment: the method by Yogesh Sharma to get the most recent Order record is superior if you have an Order ID, as you can return that for the most recent Order. the CTE above is clearer code though, so I shall keep this answer around.

Comment: I simplified the examples a bit too much it seems. There is ofc Order ID's in the order rows table, as well as running numbers for the rows on the orders. This is only a small part of what I am trying to build, and hope that I can figure something out based on these examples.

Comment: Good luck. The combination of these answers should steer you in the right direction.